# how to disable multiple mouse clicks in kendo menu UI?

Tags: kendo-ui

We are using Kendo menu UI

once we are opening and adding the list menu an activity is being created.But if you are clicking it multiple times multiple activities are being created

how to restrict kendo menu UI multiple clicks?

Code:

```
function NewAc(arg) {
    if (arg.item.id != "Mactive" && arg.item.id != "") {
        var scope = angular.element('#Div').scope();
        scope.save();
        if(!scope.isSaveSuccess) {
            selectedItem.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        default: var selectedActTypePK = arg.item.id;
        var parentActId = stageTreeView.Id;
        var htmlClient = new htmlContentClient();
        htmlClient.getHtml();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide code?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani,

Please find the below code which is being executed up on clicking the list menu item again and again

Comment: function NewAc(arg) {if (arg.item.id != "Mactive" && arg.item.id != ""){   
        var scope = angular.element('#Div').scope();
        scope.save();
        if(!scope.isSaveSuccess){
            selectedItem.preventDefault();
            return;}
            default:
                    var selectedActTypePK = arg.item.id;
                    var parentActId = stageTreeView.Id;
                    var htmlClient = new htmlContentClient();
                    htmlClient.getHtml();break;
        }
    }

Comment: Is there any event in kendo menu with which we can restrict user for only single click ?